# Methods for smearing multidimensional data

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, simulation, k-nearest-neighbour, gamlss

I have a dataset $X \in \mathbb{R}^{2p}$. Half of the parameters $X_{pre} \in \mathbb{R}^p$ represent true values without measurement biases or errors. The other half $X_{post} \in \mathbb{R}^p$ are the measured values of the same variables. I have paired data because this dataset is the result of simulation. The problem I have is that it is computationally much easier to generate $X_{pre}$ than $X_{post}$. I would like to use my complete dataset $X$ to smear future simulated datasets $X'_{pre}$ by applying the measurement bias and error.

Unfortunately the relationship between these variables is intricate. Generally the error dominates over the bias in these measurements; the median/mode are fairly close to the true value, though not always the mean because the errors can be highly skewed. The errors in the measurements of the $p$ variables are also correlated. I have tried using the `gamlss` to model these relationships one variable at a time, but this ignores the correlated errors -- and also the errors are difficult to model with `gamlss` in some cases because of how highly skewed they are, the topic of [another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257383/distribution-for-gamlss-with-minimum-non-zero-possibly-negative-threshold). Because of the difficulty, it doesn't seem feasible to me to scale this up to measuring all $p$ variables simultaneously.

One thing I have thought of is a nearest neighbors technique. Given a value $x \in \mathbb{R}^p$, I can lookup the nearest $N$ points in $X_{pre}$ and find the associated values in $X_{post}$. Rather than simply taking the mean or median of these values, however, I will sample from them, to model the smearing of the error. A few questions:

- Is this a valid procedure?
- Is there a cross-validation metric I could use to optimize $N$? I would need to compare two $p$-dimensional datasets (smeared and fully simulated), and since $p>1$ the KS test would not necessarily work.
- Are there other approaches that I could try?